# org.apache.jasper.JasperException: /WEB-INF/jsp/home.jsp (line: [159], column: [88]) equal symbol expected

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jsp

I am getting below error while using spring forms.

```
Mon Mar 22 02:51:28 IST 2021
There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
/WEB-INF/jsp/home.jsp (line: [159], column: [88]) equal symbol expected
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: /WEB-INF/jsp/home.jsp (line: [159], column: [88]) equal symbol expected
```

Here is my code for form.

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col">
<form:label for="clientName">Status</form:label>
<form:input type="text" path="status" class="form-control" id="status" disabled>
</form:input>
</div>
```

The line in which it is showing error is this.

```
<form:input type="text" path="status" class="form-control" id="status" disabled>
```

Can some body help me what is the issue with that? Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: Also if I refresh the page again the error changes to below.

This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Mon Mar 22 02:57:54 IST 2021
There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.jsp.home_jsp
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.jsp.home_jsp
 at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:435)
 at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JasperLoader.loadClass(JasperLoader.java:128)
 at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JasperLoader.loadClass(JasperLoader.java:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `disabled="true"` that is what it expects.

So the following will solve the error

```
<form:input type="text" path="status" class="form-control" id="status" disabled="true">
```